# How to test the apparition of a span?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm testing the login page , in the scenario when I enter an invalid logIn and Password , I'm looking to collect the span "Authentication Failed"

I select the span webElement by xpath '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/snack-bar-container/simple-snack-bar/span, when I test it on the navigator console , I receive the text inside the span . But when I use it on the test script , it doesn't work .

```
getSnackbar() {
   return element(by.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/snack-bar- 
container/simple-snack-bar/span'));
  }

it(' SnackBar "Authentication Failed" Appears ', () => {
  login.navigateTo();
  element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('LogIn');
  element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('pwd');
  login.logIn();
  browser.sleep(5000);
  expect(login.getSnackbar().getText()).toEqual('Failed Authentication');
});
```

I expect to receive a positive result of the test , but I receive : " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)".

Comment: Share your html and the complete error for better input on the issue.

Comment: - Expected [ Entry({ level: SEVERE, message: 'http://localhost/.../api/auth - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)', timestamp: 1560341389940, type: '' }) ] not to contain <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ level: SEVERE }))>.

Comment: could you share the html code?

Answer (score 0):

My first point would be not to use xpaths in tests as they are **very** fragile. The best way to get an element in Angular testing is to use the following

> `elementYouWant = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#id-of-element'));` 
>  OR 
>   `elementYouWant = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.class-of-element'));`

Also don't use `browser.sleep()` you're making your unit test last a minimum of 5 seconds which is far too slow. Try to await the function if it is async.

**As to the error message**
It appears like you aren't mocking out the login method. (i.e. you are making a real call to your server). You should not do this. A unit test should mock out all external dependencies.

You should create a mock `login` class with the `logIn()` method mocked and returning a failed response. Then you will be able to perform your assertion without the problem you are having.

Hope this helps

Comment: the test work fine in the case when we enter a valid username and a valid password .

Comment: in those cases, the response from the api will be 200 so no error is expected. You are expecting a different message from one you're getting back. It appears to be working correctly, you just expect the message to be slightly different